# Select Top(x) while x.Kind = "value"

Tags: c#, linq, loops

How do I select the top of the list as long as the items at the top of the list have a property with a specific value.

I need the Linq statement to see that there is a break in the sequence and the only return the top two items. The problem is that I don't know exactly how many items are going to have the correct property value.

I have been working through this problem with LinqPad 4. The code below is a copy and past from LinqPad 4. The results, "q", should not contain SomeData with an EffectiveDate of 4/5/2011 because the Kind property on hsc2 is "KindTwo".

I am trying to find the value most resent value of "Kind" and then only take the top records that match that value until I get to a record that doesn't match that value.

```
void Main()
{
    var hsc1 = new SomeData {EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011,4,5), Kind = "KindOne"};
    var hsc2 = new SomeData {EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011,4,10), Kind = "KindTwo"};
    var hsc3 = new SomeData {EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011,4,20), Kind = "KindOne"};
    var hsc4 = new SomeData {EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011,4,25), Kind = "KindOne"};

    var all = new [] {hsc1, hsc2, hsc3, hsc4};

    var lastSomeData = all.OrderByDescending((x) => x.EffectiveDate).First();

    lastSomeData.Dump();

    var q = from h in all 
            where h.Kind == lastSomeData.Kind
            orderby h.EffectiveDate descending 
            select h;

    q.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class SomeData
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate {get;set;}
    public string Kind {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fully working Console Application that does what you asked. As I was not the first to propose the use of TakeWhile in this question, please do not mark my answer as the accepted one.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace stackoverflow.com_questions_5825629_select_topx_while_x_kind_value
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var hsc1 = new SomeData { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 5), Kind = "KindOne" };
            var hsc2 = new SomeData { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 10), Kind = "KindTwo" };
            var hsc3 = new SomeData { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 20), Kind = "KindOne" };
            var hsc4 = new SomeData { EffectiveDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 25), Kind = "KindOne" };

            var all = new[] { hsc1, hsc2, hsc3, hsc4 };

            var lastSomeData = all.OrderByDescending((x) => x.EffectiveDate).First();

            var q = (from h in all
                     orderby h.EffectiveDate descending
                     select h).TakeWhile(x => x.Kind == lastSomeData.Kind);

            var result = q.ToArray();

            foreach (var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Define other methods and classes here
        class SomeData
        {
            public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
            public string Kind { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format(@"new SomeData {{ EffectiveDate = new DateTime({0}, {1}, {2}), Kind = ""{3}"" }};", EffectiveDate.Year, EffectiveDate.Month, EffectiveDate.Day, Kind);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were not the first one to recommend the TakeWhile solution but you were the first one to remove the where clause from the query and that turned out to be my blocking issue.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) method

```
DateTime filterDate = new DateTime(2011, 4, 5);
var top = q.TakeWhile(x => (DateTime.Compare(x, filterDate) != 0));
```

Comment: The filter is on the kind not on the effective date. If I use the TakeWhile with the kind I still get back the Data object with an effective date of 4/5/2011. I need to filter out the last two because the Kind property changed. I only want the first two because the Kind value matches.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it? Ordering by date descending gets you a first element of 2011/4/25 and a kind of KindOne. Since the element with date 2011/4/5 has a kind of KindOne, it's going to be included in the result.

If you just want to grab a subset, you can use the .Take(num) extension method.